# How will one stake Ether?

Tags: proof-of-stake, staking, validators

Once Ethereum makes the switch to proof of stake how will one choose to stake Ether? Will they have to use a special program or will Ether not in use be considered staked and be used to gain more Ether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After moving to Casper POS, To become a validator (mine new ethers) you will need locking up an amount of your ethers (to be bonded) by sending them to the Casper contract. If i remember they will stay locked for 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

The Ethereum Launchpad has the instructions for staking:

https://launchpad.ethereum.org/

The launchpad informs you of the requirements, including running one of the Lighthouse, Nimbus, Prysm, Teku clients.

The ETH Staker community is highly recommended.  They are very knowledgable, but their first value is "Welcoming First, Knowledgeable Second":

https://ethstaker.cc/